# android view inside cardView override corners

Tags: android

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
       ... />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="200sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But when I create new project a corners is not override. I do not why  I have this and how i can repair this

Comment: What do you actually want to do ?

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar I want to create view in cardview with background and radius and imageview in whicz I put  phote and steal have a radius

Comment: Is it fine if you use a third part library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For assigning cornerRadius to CardView just Use

```
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
```

in your CardView to assign corner's to your cardView .
And for Rounded ImageView use  **RoundedImageView** library .

**First Step :**
Add the below dependency to your app level gradle file

```
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
```

**Second Step :**
And in your project level gradle file make sure you have inside your repositories block:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**Third Step :**

Now just replace your ImageView with the RoundedImageView :
For eg like this :

```
com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/photo1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
        app:riv_border_width="2dip"
        app:riv_border_color="#333333"
        app:riv_mutate_background="true"
        app:riv_tile_mode="repeat"
        app:riv_oval="true" />
```

Here you can change the corner_radius as you like and also if you want to keep it oval as shape then mark it app:riv_oval as true else mark it as false .

Comment: Happy it helped